# Aligning two anchors side by side

Tags: html, css

Here is an image of my current progress:

[image]

As you can see, the anchors are aligining themselves incorrectly.They should be equidistanct from eachother and aligned symmetrically.

What am I doing incorrectly that I need to be doing to get the two anchor elements to align correctly left to right, having the right anchor pushed up obviously.

I'd prefer to **not have to alter the positioning**

```css
a.genericbuttonleft {
  position: static;
  margin: 0px;
  //float:left;

}
a.genericbuttonright {
  position: static;
  margin: 52%;
  //float:right;

}
.profileinfo {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #202020;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 20px 25px 20px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.profileinfo h1 {
  font: 40px/45px'HelveticaNeue-Light', sans-serif-light;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
}
.profileinfo a {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 34px;
  display: block;
  width: 260px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 18px 0 16px 0;
  font: 25px/25px'-apple-system', BlinkMacSystemFont, 'HelveticaNeue', Roboto;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #13cc3a;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="profileinfo">
  <h1><!-- this needs to stay here even though not being used --></h1>
  <a class="genericbuttonleft">Search Profiles</a> 
  <a class="genericbuttonright">Create a Profile</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the absolute positioning to start with...

Comment: @Paulie_D I cannot. Its imperative to the existing structure

Comment: BTW `//` isn't valid CSS comment syntax

Comment: It looks like you have a typo in your `genericbuttonright` margin, you have it at `margin: 52%x;`. Plus, you are using incorrect comment syntax. Instead of margins also, I would consider using simple left: 0, and right: 0; if you need absolute positioning.

Comment: If it's "imperative to the existing structure" but is breaking your page, I think you need a re-think. Can you not add a class to those buttons to override it?

Comment: Then use different position values for each link.

Comment: I added 'display:inline' and it seemed to resolve it

Comment: @Paulie_D Well it actually made them align correctly. My final task is to make them space out from eachother as one on the absolute left and one on the absolute right. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```css
a.genericbuttonleft {
  margin: 0px;
  left: 0;
}
a.genericbuttonright {
  right: 0;
}
.profileinfo {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #202020;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 20px 25px 20px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.profileinfo h1 {
  font: 40px/45px'HelveticaNeue-Light', sans-serif-light;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
}
.profileinfo a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  display: block;
  width: 260px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 18px 0 16px 0;
  font: 25px/25px'-apple-system', BlinkMacSystemFont, 'HelveticaNeue', Roboto;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #13cc3a;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="profileinfo">
  <h1><!-- this needs to stay here even though not being used --></h1>
  <a class="genericbuttonleft">Search Profiles</a> 
  <a class="genericbuttonright">Create a Profile</a>
</div>
```